# Is a double 2x6 header adequate for a double sliding door?

Tags: doors, basement

I'm going to make a sliding door in my basement. I'm going to use the double 2x6 header. I wanted to know if it's enough to support the weight of two floors above and snow, and if there is any calculation to check.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**2x6 is almost never adequate** in an exterior wall for any span over 24", especially if you have a floor above and snow loads.

A double 2x10 would be more standard, but in some cases LVL could be required. I would have a local expert take a look. We're guessing.

Comment: In support of this answer, the proper header for an 8' garage door is 2x12.

Comment: I haven't seen a 2x12 used in residential construction for a couple decades. They've been largely supplanted with 11-1/4" LVL, either due to scarcity or more reliable load specs.

Comment: I'm going with them because they're _significantly_ cheaper than an LVL, even of a slightly smaller dimension. Maybe I'm shopping at the wrong stores...

Comment: I guess an 8' garage door is smaller than modern standard, so that makes sense. Most are 9'.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If it is **not** a load-bearing wall, then the purpose of the lintel is to prevent the sagging of the beam above it from jamming or damaging the window/door.

If it is a load-bearing wall, then the purpose of the lintel is to distribute the load from above to the studs at the ends.  You should really talk to an architect or Engineer.

Comment: It's an exterior wall, aren't those generally load bearing by definition?

Comment: no,  eg, below a gable end there is not much load. except possibly some load contentrations.